# Why is the size of files compiled by gnu gcc and cygwin gcc different?

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, codeblocks, gnu

This is just a small "Hello World" program, which when compiled using Cygwin GCC and GNU GCC is different in size.

```
#include <iostream>
main(){
cout<<"Hello World";}
```

The cygwin version is only 60.7 Kb, while for GNU it is 978 Kb. Why is this so, if they both use GCC only? I am using codeblocks IDE.

Comment: One of them probably has debugging symbols in it, the other doesn't.

Comment: Can you explain this please?

Comment: Did you use all the same compiler options? Are they the same version of GCC? Are the object file formats the same? Did you link them both dynamically, or is the GNU one linked statically? There are many possible reasons why they could be different sizes.

Comment: Setting for both of them are same, how to check for object file formats? Cygwin is 4.9.2 and GNU is 4.8.1, linking is dynamic for both.

Comment: On Unix I'd use the `file` command to see the file format, I don't know how to do it on Windows.

Comment: You can use file aswell on Cygwin.

Comment: Cygwin GCC is also a GNU GCC by definition. GCC acronym means "GNU Compiler Collection". Perhaps you used codeblocks in case of "GNU GCC" , and it have linked some libraries to the executable due to the default project settings. At the other case perhaps you used only the basic command line options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I suspect that on cygwin the `-g` parameter is not taken implicitly but on gnu(mingw installed with codeblocks?) gcc it is taken implicitly.</strike> Edit: seems foolish when read again

try adding `-g` when you are compiling on cygwin, your executable should be larger. 
on codeblocks(mingw) try the release target which is usually created.
alternately use the `strip` command.

Comment: try strip on the large binary

Comment: -b on gnu reduces the size to 60.7 kb for gnu! How does this works? but, the size of cygwin remains same everytime!